# Magento Third Party Model Override

Tags: php, magento

I am attempting to override only one portion of a third party extensions Model (the "Userprofile" functionality) to include a few more columns and calls to retrieve the new info. Here is the third party config.xml:

```
<models>
            <marketplace>
                <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>marketplace_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </marketplace>
            <marketplace_mysql4>
                <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <product>
                        <table>marketplace_product</table>
                    </product>
                    <userprofile> 
                        <table>marketplace_userdata</table>
                    </userprofile>
                    <feedback> 
                        <table>marketplace_datafeedback</table>
                    </feedback>
                    <saleperpartner> 
                        <table>marketplace_saleperpartner</table>
                    </saleperpartner>
                    <saleslist> 
                        <table>marketplace_saleslist</table>
                    </saleslist>
                </entities>
            </marketplace_mysql4>
        </models>
```

Here is my own config.xml:

```
<models>
            <zerobars_marketplacepayment>
                <class>ZeroBars_Marketplacepayment_Model</class>
       </zerobars_marketplacepayment>


          <marketplace>
               <rewrite>
                   <userprofile>ZeroBars_Marketplacepayment_Model_Userprofile</userprofile>
               </rewrite>
          </marketplace>
          <marketplace_mysql4>
              <rewrite>
                  <userprofile>ZeroBars_Marketplacepayment_Model_Mysql4_Userprofile</userprofile>
                   <userprofile_collection>ZeroBars_Marketplacepayment_Model_Mysql4_Userprofile_Collection</userprofile_collection>
              </rewrite>
          </marketplace_mysql4>

       </models>
```

I've copied over all of the Userprofile documents into my Model structure exactly as they are in the original extension with the exception of replacing the "marketplace" namespace with my own:

```
<?php
class ZeroBars_Marketplacepayment_Model_Userprofile extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('zerobars_marketplacepayment/userprofile');

    }

    public function getPartnerProfileById($partnerId) {
        $data = array();
        if ($partnerId != '') {
            $collection = Mage::getModel('zerobars_marketplacepayment/userprofile')->getCollection();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$partnerId));
            $user = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($partnerId);

....
```

However I am still getting a "Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in /home/devzerob/public_html/app/code/local/ZeroBars/Marketplacepayment/Model/Userprofile.php on line 14"

The error is originating in the $collection line of the PHP file. Am I missing anything? Do I need to do any overriding in the  section of the config?

Comment: It has occurred to me that I may need to add a corresponding <entities><userprofile><table> line to my config after looking more closely at this. Are there any good articles on how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you model file, through which you are intending to rewrite a custom model extension, has some problems. I will notice you what are the main problem that I can see now.

- *Model extends wrong class*

  Your model class now extending class  `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`, which in your case is wrong you need to extend `Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Userprofile`. This is because you are overwriting this class. So it is essential that you custom class should inherit from this class itself.
- *Referencing to a wrong model*

  Now model collection is carried out by this code snippet

  ```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('zerobars_marketplacepayment/userprofile')->getCollection();
  ```

  This tells to magento that, hey magento I need all data collection from the model `ZeroBars_Marketplacepayment_Model_Userprofile`. This method definitely raise an error, since this model refers to your module and does not contain any collection,resources(I assumes so). So you may probably need to use

  ```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection();
  ```

  Now the collection refers to `Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Userprofile` and it does have a collection,resources defined. I also hope that `mageuserid` is defined by this module itself.
- *What you can do ?*

In your question, you mentioned that, you need to add some extra column fields to custom tables. For that you need to use some upgrade scripts. Some reference for this is given here [**1**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/adding_a_new_column_to_an_existing_table_in_the_database), [**2**](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/). You may get more tutorials out there.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much programmer_rkt! I did write an upgrade script that is working fine so that part is taken care of. The big piece I was missing was the "extends Extension" part. All is well now, I owe you a virtual coffee or something. :-)